# Is there a difference in the usage of "eben" vs. "vorhin"?

Tags: word-choice, difference, word-usage, adverb

In the following examples both variants work:

> **Vorhin** lief mein Rechner noch einwandfrei, jetzt bleibt der Bildschirm schwarz.
>   **Eben** lief mein Rechner noch einwandfrei, jetzt bleibt der Bildschirm schwarz.

Is there a difference in the meaning of *"eben"* or *"vorhin"*? When do we prefer one over the other?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In my feeling, *vorhin* might be a bit longer ago than *eben*. If something happened in the immediate past (a few seconds ago), then you can say *eben* but not *vorhin* to express this. Moreover, *eben* sounds a bit more colloquial than *vorhin* to me. A less colloquial word is *gerade*, which can also express the immediate past.

Another thing is that *eben* has a lot more meanings than *vorhin*:

> Eben war der Flachbildschirm noch eben; dann hat mein Bruder mal eben gegengetreten – nicht eben nett.

(Note that both the first and the last instance of *eben* could be replaced with *gerade*.)

Comment: +1 - nice "graphic" example :-)

Comment: Die 3 Ebenen des Wortes `eben` sind nett, aber einen Zeitunterschied auszumachen halte ich für Einbildung. `colloquial` accepted.

Comment: @user: Keine Einbildung `:-)` _eben_ kann die unmittelbare Vergangenheit ausdrücken (vor wenigen Sekunden); _vorhin_ würde da nicht passen. (Übrigens hat _eben_ noch mehr Bedeutungsebenen.)

Comment: @user: See also my updated answer.

Comment: Well, you repeat your assertion, but without argument. I say, you can use 'vorhin' for exact the same events in time, something which is just over.

Comment: @user: So you would say "vorhin lief mein Rechner noch einwandfrei" if that's just seconds ago? You wouldn't at least _prefer_ "eben" or "gerade"?

Comment: What I would prefer is not a prove or indicate, because I could - for instance - use 'eben' or 'gerade' because 'vorhin' might be an more old fashion expression (not that I say so - it just could be the case) or there might be other reasons to prefer one of the many, possible ways to express it. Only if I would meanwhile prefer 'vorhin' in other circumstances it could be an indicator. But I don't have a statistic of which term I use how often in what circumstances. I can only say, that if we would stand at a station, and after - whoooosh - an ICE passing it, and you would say: ...

Comment: ... "Vorhin, dass war der ICE 'Karl Kraus'", I wouldn't raise an eyebrow.

Comment: @user: Maybe this is a regional thing? Where did you grow up? (And note that I meant "prefer" only in the sense of "which expresses the immediate past better".)

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt: Subjectively, I'd also use *eben* for a moment seconds or minutes ago, while *vorhin* would refer to a moment that is longer ago. The line between the two is very blurry, so for most instances, you could use the words interchangeably. I often hear "eben" even for things that were hours ago, though I think I never heard "vorhin" for something that just happened. Might still be regional, of course. User unknown's example "gerade" sounds even more like "just now", and can be combined to "gerade eben"... Now which one was longer ago? ;)

Comment: @OregonGhost: I didn't even think of "gerade eben" - nice! And thanks for confirming that "vorhin" is rather unusual for something that just happened. I thought a bit more about "eben", and I think you can use it well in the following case: You meet with someone, maybe even talk a bit, and then say: "Ach übrigens, eben ist mit doch Jens begegnet ..." This could then well be some hours ago. It's still sort of the very recent past since you met shortly ago, and the hours before don't really count - at least that's my feeling.

Answer (score 8):

I think the two words are synonyms with the exact same meaning.

Maybe there is a situation I'd prefer *"eben"*: when I want to **emphasize** that somehting suddenly, maybe unpredictedly **has changed:**

> Eben noch funktionierte es.
>   Eben war er noch da.

Which contains an element of surprise. Also, not much time has passed since the situation has changed. The following sentences with "vorhin" aren't as strong:

> Vorhin funktionierte es noch.
>   Vorhin war er noch da.

But it's very subtle in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

Hier Antwort, habe im Internet gefunden. [image]

Comment: Eine Quellenangabe wäre hilfreich (zum Beispiel als Link unter dem Wort "Internet").

Comment: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Deutsch_Wann_Zeiten_jetzt_vorhin.svg